# Compare elements of list within a list

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
[[846033, 365, 202], [849432, 276, 140], [821121, 209, 111], [820180, 244, 133], [849401, 971, 572], [848613, 790, 596], [846978, 914, 272]]
```

The first element of the little lists is the "idnumber" and the other 2 elements are data I want to compare.

The thing I want to do is this: I want to delete the elements of the big list for which at least one of the two data numbers is under 250. The answer should look like this:

```
[[849401, 971, 572], [848613, 790, 596], [846978, 914, 272]].
```

I tried to make a for loop in a for loop but I failed:

```
def zonderRuis(sigIdSpot=[[846033, 365, 202], [849432, 276, 140], [821121, 209, 111], [820180, 244, 133], [849401, 971, 572], [848613, 790, 596], [846978, 914, 272]]):
    ruisvrij=[]
    for i in range(len(sigIdSpot)):
        for r in i:
            if r[2]>=250 and r[3]>=250:
                ruisvrij.append(r)
    return ruisvrij
```

Comment: The reason this isn't working is that `range` returns a list of integers; `for r in sigIdSpot:` would have worked fine instead of the two for loops that don't access your actual list at all. (Well, that and using `r[2]` and `r[3]` instead of 1 and 2.

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm going to use this one.

Answer (score 8):

```
[x for x in data if all(y >= 250 for y in x[1:])]
```

Comment: Was going to post my own, but not much point now. Except: `any(y < 250...` would be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @MattH: Would it? Both will short-circuit at the same place, no?

Comment: @Wooble: Good point. Okay, `any` and `<` more closely reflect the OP's description of the constraints :)

Comment: @MattH you're probably right about the description. On the other hand `if not all(y < 250...` requires that one extra mental tick to process ...

Answer (score 1):

Just a point about iteration:

```
for i in range(len(sigIdSpot)):
    x = sigIdSpot[i]
    print x

# becomes more clear if you do the following:
for x in sigIdSpot:
    print x
```

Now if you want to debug your code, you can put some prints to see what's going on with your code:

```
def zonderRuis(sigIdSpot=[[846033, 365, 202], [849432, 276, 140], [821121, 209, 111], [820180, 244, 133], [849401, 971, 572], [848613, 790, 596], [846978, 914, 272]]):
    ruisvrij=[]
    for i in range(len(sigIdSpot)):
        print 'i is:', i
        for r in i:
            print 'r is:', r
            if r[2]>=250 and r[3]>=250:
                ruisvrij.append(r)
                print 'r appended to ruisvrij:', ruisvrij
    return ruisvrij
```

Remember, the interactive shell is our best friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [15]: l = [[846033, 365, 202], [849432, 276, 140], [821121, 209, 111], [820180, 244, 133], [849401, 971, 572], [848613, 790, 596], [846978, 914, 272]]

In [16]: [sub for sub in l if min(sub[1:]) >= 250]
Out[16]: [[849401, 971, 572], [848613, 790, 596], [846978, 914, 272]]
```

Comment: `min()` needs to loop through *all* values; using `all()` would be more efficient as it'll short-circuit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: True. But the OP is quite explicit about the "other **2** elements". ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 =  [[846033, 365, 202], [849432, 276, 140], [821121, 209, 111], [820180, 244, 133], [849401, 971, 572], [848613, 790, 596], [846978, 914, 272]]
list2 = []
for x in list1:
    if x[1] > 250 and x[2] > 250:
        lijst1.append(x)
```

Comment: An explanation of the code is always better than just a code dump.